# Tableau: Average by Dimension

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to average `N` by `Type` for values of `Inst`

My data is set up as:

```
Type, Inst, N
A, A1, 4
A, A1, 13
A, A1, 13
A, A2, 4
A, A3, 5
B, B1, 4
B, b2, 10
```

So I would like to see a table (or bar chart) with `A: 13, B:7`. Any suggestions? 
If I put `AVG(N)` in rows and `Type` in columns I get `A: 7.8, B:7`

The problem is that Tableau is averaging all `N` per `Type`, but I want the numerator to be the total `N` for the `Type` while the denominator is the number of unique `Inst` within that `Type`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a calculated field `desired_avg` as

```
{FIXED [Inst] : SUM([N])}
```

put it in the sheet .

select aggregation as `AVG` and not `SUM`

Let me know if that worked !

Comment: yes, thank you! I was looking for a solution that used LoD expressions

Comment: any suggestion on how to get cell reference lines / box plots for each type?

Comment: You need to share your workbook / sample data to get me going on this !

Answer (score 2):

Define the following calculated field

```
Sum(N) / countd(Inst)
```

Comment: thanks, suggestions if i wanted a median instead of avg?

Comment: Could just be Median(N) -- if you don't care about multiple instances of the same type being treated as distinct values. Otherwise, you'll have to think about what exactly you want the Median to represent and define the calculation accordingly.